# My brightness Control is not working (amd)

Tags: drivers, brightness, amdgpu, nomodeset

I actually have tried many ways to correct this
Perhaps I was able to correct it adding a

```
acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor
```

in the grub configuration file( in GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash")
But after a day when i star my laptop another problem occured
Guess what!! blank screen
then i have to add nomodeset in grub in grub page.
Then i see that all brightness control has lost(Empty folder in sys/class/backlight).....!!

What i am supposed to do?
can u suggest some proprietary driver... For and graphic card
My laptop is Asus VivoBook Ryzen 5 Quad Core having acpi_video

Comment: What OS/release are you using?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Whoever comes here, try steps from here https://www.debugpoint.com/2016/10/2-ways-fix-laptop-brightness-problem-ubuntu-linux/ (updated in April 2021)

Answer (score 0):

Guys I actually solved the problem by installing amdgpu_pro released for ubuntu 20.04.
Also it solved my blank screen problem after grub page .

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add some more info about how you solved the issue.